# Can't get object by name instead of array position with json path

Tags: json, jsonpath

I need to get the first pet name of the first "other" object which in this case is "john", I am using this JsonPath `$[1].other.pets[0].name` and it works correctly but I can't use `[1]` because the first "other" element could be at `[0]` in the next JSON response.

My **JSON** is:

```
[
    {
        "load": {}
    },
    {
        "other": {
            "pets": [
                {
                    "name": "john",
                    "age": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "load": {}
    },
    {
        "other": {
            "pets": [
                {
                    "name": "mike",
                    "age": "6"
                },
                {
                    "name": "pluto",
                    "age": "3"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Any idea of the JsonPath I should use?

I need to get an object by its name and not by array position, if there is more than one object with the same name get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of using `$[1].other.pets[0].name` you could use `$[*].other.pets[0].name`. The result will be a list of the first pet's name of all 'other' objects. In your example

```
[
  "john",
  "mike"
]
```

Now, just pick the first element of this list.

Doing that in JavaScript using "jsonpath-plus" (for example) would look like this:

```
const result = JSONPath({path: '$[*].other.pets[0].name', json})[0]
```